# AngularJs : ng-click() accepting invalid arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I use the following code snippet to list an array of objects in html document 
, it shows the list of link accurately ...

```
<div ng-repeat="item in List">
  <a ng-click="Show('{{item.name}}');"> ShowName </a>
</div>
```

it outputs the following html code:

```
   <a ng-click="Show('name1')">ShowName</a>
   .
   .
   .
    <a ng-click="Show('//upto nth name')">ShowName</a>
```

Here is my angular code :

```
      $scope.Show=
      function(getName)
      {
         alert(getName);
      }
```

but when I click on any link it shows "{{item.name}}" instead of showing "name1" or respective name in the alertbox...

I also tried

```
        Show(&#39;{{item.name}}&#39;);
```

but the result is same...

what I am doing wrong????

Comment: you can use ng-click="Show(item.name);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to use `{{}}` inside an Angular directive. Your code should be like this:

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in List">

   <a ng-click="Show(item.name)"> ShowName </a>

 </div>
```

Comment: @mubsher no problem, do you mind upvoting the answer?

Comment: @urielSilve  i have 11 reputatuion which are not enough to upvote any anwer or question...i'll upvote as i get upto 15 reputations...

Answer (score 1):

You can either use following style

```
<li ng-repeat="item  in List">
  <a href="" ng-click="clickit($index)">{{item.name}}</a>
</li>
```

here $index represent index of your array. i prefer to use this because here you can access full object.then just do what you want.

```
 $scope.clickit = function(x) {
    console.log($scope.List[x])
}
```

if you don't like the above style you can use the below style

```
<li ng-repeat="item  in List">
  <a href="" ng-click="clickit(item.name)">{{item.name}}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but i dnt understand the term $index
what would $index contain in it i mean what will be the value of
 $index =? 
 in each repetition,

whether it contains the object in "item" or something like 
 $index['0'] will eqaul List['0'] ?

Comment: $index is the index/key ( as like $key in php foreach ) of your collection . Assume you have an array named List  that contain five object. so List[0] represent first item of array. List[1] represent second item of array and so on. for first repetition/ iteration $index will be 0. for second repetition/ iteration $index will be 1 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are using `'` and `{}` when passing the variable as an argument to the function.

Change

`<a ng-click="Show('{{item.name}}');"> ShowName </a>`

to

`<a ng-click="Show(item.name);"> ShowName </a>`